# Synergy Mouse cursor jumps to center on server computer

Tags: mac, synergy, mouse-cursor

I just downloaded synergy 1.5.1 onto my 2010 Macbook running on Mavericks (the server) and my 2006 iMac running on Snow Leopard (the client). Whenever I move the mouse cursor over to the client computer. It seems that a invisible mouse cursor jumps to the center of the screen on the server computer. Depending on whats currently there, the invisible cursor will trigger hover effects in what seems to be in a small area in the center of the screen. Is there some workaround to avoid this? While it's not the end of the world, it does get annoying!

Comment: Same issue here!

Comment: Actually in my case, the cursor keeps showing on the server, but exactly on the center of screen